# Why is Keras Input(shape=) expecting shape (1,) for dim=100 vectors

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I still try to wrap my head around the `shape=` argument of `keras.Input()` - I tried to conduct the most simple dummy net and and input for testing purposes:

```
import keras
import numpy as np

def build_model(shape):
    f_input = keras.Input(shape=(shape[1],))  # (100,)
    d1 = keras.layers.Dense(50, activation='tanh')(f_input)
    softmax = keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')(d1)
    return keras.Model(f_input, softmax)

data = np.random.random((1000, 100))
model = build_model(data.shape)
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='SGD')
model.fit(x=data, y=data)
```

But keras still raised the error:
`ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_2 to have shape (1,) but got array with shape (100,)`

What am I doing wrong - my shape is defined as (,100) as I expect an *arbitrary batch size of vectors with dimension 100* as stated in the keras docs. Why does this **ValueError** occur - I totally expect arrays with the shape (100,) or not? - do I have to reshape the data before?

Any hints appreacheated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issues is not with your input shape. You are giving the input shape absolutely in the right manner. The issue is that you are passing a `(1000*100)` dimensional vector instead of a `(1,100)` dimensional vector in place of y during the `model.fit`.

```
import numpy as np

def build_model(shape):
    f_input = keras.layers.Input(shape=(shape[1],))  # (100,)
    d1 = keras.layers.Dense(50, activation='tanh')(f_input)
    softmax = keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')(d1)
    return keras.Model(f_input, softmax)

data = np.random.random((1000, 100))
model = build_model(data.shape)
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='SGD')
model.fit(x=data, y=np.random.random((1000,))) #Change this to your actual y array!!
```

```
32/32 [==============================] - 0s 628us/step - loss: 0.2295
```

This runs just fine for me.